# Error - [spfx-serve] The api entry could not be loaded: node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to do the tutorial found here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

But upon entering the command: gulp serve, I ge the following:

```
$ gulp serve
Build target: DEBUG
[10:08:26] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\projects\helloworld-webpart\gulpfile.js
[10:08:26] Starting 'serve'...
[10:08:26] Starting gulp
[10:08:26] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
[10:08:26] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 3.28 ms
[10:08:26] Starting subtask 'spfx-serve'...
[10:08:26] [spfx-serve] To load your scripts, use this query string: ?debug=true&noredir=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
[10:08:26] Starting server...
[10:08:26] Error - [spfx-serve] The api entry could not be loaded: node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/
[10:08:26] Error - [spfx-serve] Error: Invalid glob argument:
[10:08:26] Error - 'spfx-serve' sub task errored after 125 ms
 Invalid glob argument:
[10:08:26] 'serve' errored after 133 ms
[10:08:26]
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

I am using:

```
$ node -v
v10.19.0
```

and:

```
$ npm -v
6.13.4
```

Comment: Did you run 'npm install' first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running

> npm i @microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench

Reference:[Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench)